# warning when using bitfield with unsigned char

Tags: c

This is my bitfield

```
struct {
    unsigned char v64 : 1;
    unsigned char leg : 7;
} valid;
```

Then I get the warning:

```
main.c:17:3: warning: type of bit-field ‘v64’ is a GCC extension [-pedantic]
main.c:18:3: warning: type of bit-field ‘leg’ is a GCC extension [-pedantic]
```

If I change to `int` there is no warning. But I want a bitfield of a byte (unsigned char).

How?

Comment: `int` has a special meaning inside of bit fields. What is `sizeof(struct valid)`?

Comment: @Pubby: using int, = 4; unsigned char = 1.

Comment: This is a very common compiler extension.  Maybe you ought to ignore the warning to have your cake and eat it.

Answer (score 14):

Remove the `gcc` `-pedantic` option if you don't want to get the warning.

In C99, `gcc` issues a warning with `-pedantic` but it is permitted to have an implementation defined type for the bit-field (like `unsigned char`).

> (C99, 6.7.2.1p4) "A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of _Bool, signed int, unsigned int, or some other implementation-defined type."

In C90, only `int`, `unsigned int` and `signed int` are permitted.

> (C90, 6.5.2.1) "A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of one of int, unsigned int, or signed int"

Actually in both C90 and C99 the warning is not required by C (it is undefined behavior in C90 only but C doesn't not require a warning for undefined behavior). The warning is added by `gcc` with `-pedantic` for information only.

Comment: Is ```unsigned long int``` permitted as well is C90?

Comment: @avivgood2 *"In C90, only int, unsigned int and signed int are permitted."* So no, `unsigned long int` is not permitted.